# Magento Orders without status

Tags: magento, payment

When I checkout using payment method "Back Transfer Payment" and even another one I installed called "Credit Card by Phone", the orders are created without a status.

I tried to find where it gets the status and sets it but I couldn't find it.

Can you help me?

order state is: payment_review
order status is: NULL

and I have a status assigned for the state payment_review

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem is with the extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/official-skrill-moneybookers-quick-checkout-enterprise-module.html

I don't know why but when this one is disabled it just works.
When it's enabled both modules of Bank Transfer and Credit Card by Phone don't save any status when creating the order.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the status and state in the database (in sales_flat_order table).

After you got the status and state, you can check in **System -> Order statuses** if you have correspondant statuses.

Please come back with the information and we may help more.

Thanks

Comment: order state is: payment_review
order status is: NULL

and I have a status assigned for the state payment_review

Comment: order status to NULL is very strange... Check in module files for a setStatus or setState call (Find in path with phpStorm) this may help. What is the name of these extensions ? do you have links ?

Comment: The Bank Transfer Payment Method comes already with magento and the Credit Card by Phone is this one: [Credit Card By Phone](http://www.customy.com/credit-card-by-phone.html) I searched for "setStatus" and "setState" on the credit card by phone and nothing appeared.

Comment: do you know what can it be?

Comment: I really don't know sorry, i recommend you to disable one by one all modules that are suspect to alter order and statuses and check what can cause this... And triple check your configuration. Sorry and good luck in your research